# Trouble importing Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

When trying to import qiskit I obtain following error:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/__init__.py:63: RuntimeWarning: Could not import the Aer provider from the qiskit-aer package. Install qiskit-aer or check your installation.
  warnings.warn('Could not import the Aer provider from the qiskit-aer '
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/__init__.py:73: RuntimeWarning: Could not import the IBMQ provider from the qiskit-ibmq-provider package. Install qiskit-ibmq-provider or check your installation.
  warnings.warn('Could not import the IBMQ provider from the '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-578b7f7e9727> in <module>
----> 1 import qiskit

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/__init__.py in <module>
     78 # Moved to after IBMQ and Aer imports due to import issues
     79 # with other modules that check for IBMQ (tools)
---> 80 from qiskit.execute import execute  # noqa
     81 from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble, schedule  # noqa
     82 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/execute.py in <module>
     24 import logging
     25 from time import time
---> 26 from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble, schedule
     27 from qiskit.qobj.utils import MeasLevel, MeasReturnType
     28 from qiskit.pulse import Schedule

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/__init__.py in <module>
     33 
     34 from .assemble import assemble
---> 35 from .transpile import transpile
     36 from .schedule import schedule

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpile.py in <module>
     22 from qiskit.providers.models import BackendProperties
     23 from qiskit.providers.models.backendproperties import Gate
---> 24 from qiskit.transpiler import Layout, CouplingMap, PropertySet, PassManager
     25 from qiskit.transpiler.basepasses import BasePass
     26 from qiskit.dagcircuit import DAGCircuit

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/__init__.py in <module>
    412 """
    413 
--> 414 from .runningpassmanager import FlowController
    415 from .passmanager import PassManager
    416 from .passmanager_config import PassManagerConfig

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py in <module>
     21 from time import time
     22 
---> 23 from qiskit.dagcircuit import DAGCircuit
     24 from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag, dag_to_circuit
     25 from .propertyset import PropertySet

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/dagcircuit/__init__.py in <module>
     39    DAGCircuitError
     40 """
---> 41 from .dagcircuit import DAGCircuit
     42 from .dagnode import DAGNode
     43 from .dagdepnode import DAGDepNode

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/dagcircuit/dagcircuit.py in <module>
     29 import math
     30 
---> 31 import retworkx as rx
     32 import networkx as nx
     33 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/retworkx/__init__.py in <module>
      7 # that they have been altered from the originals.
      8 
----> 9 from .retworkx import *
     10 
     11 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'retworkx.retworkx'
```

Have I installed Qiskit to the target directory incorrectly?
I attempted to install Qiskit in Terminal using:
`python3 -m pip install qiskit -t /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.
I navigated to the path manually and I could find all the qiskit modules, including the `retworkx` modules (whatever it may be).
If anybody has experienced this sort of error before and happens to know a fix, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Can you open an interactive console and run `import retworkx`?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you install Qiskit after opening anaconda and then terminal from Anaconda and use `pip install qiskit`. For more info visit, you can try visiting https://qiskit.org

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by upgrading my python version:https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/1040